# Django Field Regex Validation

Tags: regex, django

I am trying to create a model to store an hashtag.

The validator doesn't seem to be working, making the field accept all inputs, and I can't find the solution.

Here is my model:

```
class Hashtags(models.Model):
    hashtag_validator = RegexValidator(r'^[#](\w+)$', "Hashtag doesn't comply.")
    hashtag_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    hashtag_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[hashtag_validator],   unique=True)

def get_id(self):
    return self.hashtag_id

def get_text(self):
    return self.hashtag_text
```

Answer (score 9):

You can alter it to the below given code to see it working

```
hashtag_validator = CharField(
        max_length=50,
        required=True, #if you want that field to be mandatory
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex='^[#](\w+)$',
                message='Hashtag doesnt comply',
            ),
        ]
    )
```

Hope that helps!!

---

If that is causing problem you can try writing your own validator

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import re
def validate_hash(value):
    reg = re.compile('^[#](\w+)$')
    if not reg.match(value) :
        raise ValidationError(u'%s hashtag doesnot comply' % value)
```

and change your model field to

```
hashtag_validator = models.Charfield(validators=[validate_hash])
```

Comment: Still not working, not sure whats going on.
I changed the hashtag_text to what you posted.

My tests are creating an hashtag and saving it into the db.

Answer (score 2):

Very late to the party so I doubt that this is still a problem for OP, but I will leave this here just for posterity and people that happen to come across this post. Probably you are instantiating and saving an object directly, e.g `Hashtags(hashtag_text='invalid-tag').save()`. [This will not call the validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects). The validators are only called when `full_clean` or `clean` is called, which is only done automatically if you go through a `ModelForm`. If you instantiate objects manually, either through the constructor or the object collection `Hashtags.objects.create` the validators will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to S.Ali answer:

based on example from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/#writing-validators)

```
def uncvalidator(value):
    """Custom UNC path validator"""
    import re
    from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
    UNC_REGEX = r'^local.company/some/share'
    regex = re.compile(UNC_REGEX, re.IGNORECASE)
    if not regex.match(value):
        raise ValidationError(
            _('Entered path %(value)s is incorrect.'),
            params={'value': value},
              )

unc = models.CharField(
    validators=[uncvalidator],
)
```